# popup is not going to show

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, vuejs2

```js
mounted: function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.popup-youtube11, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
            disableOn: 700,
            type: 'iframe',
            mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
            removalDelay: 160,
            preloader: false,
            fixedContentPos: false
          });
          $('.popup-youtube12, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
            disableOn: 700,
            type: 'iframe',
            mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
            removalDelay: 160,
            preloader: false,
            fixedContentPos: false
          });
          $('.popup-youtube13, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
            disableOn: 700,
            type: 'iframe',
            mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
            removalDelay: 160,
            preloader: false,
            fixedContentPos: false
          });
        });
    },
```

```html
<div class="row home-vid">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumb thumb-caption">
        <figcaption><p>some text here</p></figcaption>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb">
        <a class="popup-youtube11" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8E6xsac2MU">
          <img src="../.././images/CM.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="hover-opaque">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle text-center" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

i am using magnific popup plugin in my project i am integrating video in my project as shown above code.but the problem i am facing is sometimes it opens popup but sometimes it redirect me to the youtube page.
i want to show popup when user click on the image.

Comment: Seems to be working for me.
Check, if the jquery code is reached by using the debugger (and a breakpoint) of your browser. Maybe the argument is never reached!

Comment: Have you tried removing `$(document).ready(function() {` wrapper in `mounted`? It might be a problem

Comment: but the same code is properly running on the the another page.i am facing this problem only on my home page